# How to convert ouput into uppercases in kali linux shell

Tags: bash, shell, kali-linux

I need to convert from 'ifconfig' command output to Uppercases:

I've tried like this:

```
ifconfig | tr [:upper:]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Kali Linux uses bash as the default shell. To convert the output of `ifconfig` from lowercase to uppercase in a bash shell run the following command:

```
ifconfig | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

The `|` character is used to pipe the output of `ifconfig` to `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` . The `tr` command in bash understands the POSIX keywords `:lower:` and `:upper:` because bash is a POSIX-compliant shell.